# Liferay custom attributes blank only after login

Tags: java, mysql, sql, liferay-6.2

I created two custom attributes linked to the User resource in my Liferay 6.2 CE GA1 Installation. 
In my local environment I have no problems when I read these attributes but in production environment, *any time I login*, I get blank when I try to retrieve these fields.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are both environments of same version?

Comment: yes it is the same version of Liferay in both environments.

Comment: Please show piece of code that you are storing/reading custom attributes with.

Comment: The problem is not related to my code, in fact executing a simple test using the _Liferay Rest Api JSONWS_ **/expandovalue/get-data** to get and add value **/expandovalue/add-value** , in my production environment the problem after login arises and my custom attributes are blank.

Comment: I guess your local and production server's setup of liferay and DB would be different and might be you forgot to create custom field on your production environment.